# What's the smallest duration condition that will still deal damage?

Tags: guild-wars-2

By default, Poison, Burning, and Bleed effects last a set number of seconds, dealing damage each "Tick".

While Poisons and Burning can be extended by reapplying the buff, bleeds cannot. All three *can*, however, benefit from traits, runes, and sigils that increase the duration of a specific debuff.

For example, the 2-piece bonus for the Rune of the Balefire is 15% burn duration. If you then look at a skill that usually applies a 1 second burn, you'll notice the tooltip now lists it as lasting 1 1/4 seconds. (It rounds to the nearest quarter second increment).

My question is, does that extra 15% of one second actually increase the number of times the condition ticks and deals damage? Or do I need a full second for there to be an actual increase in damage / ticks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it turns out this is very easy to test on a Rifle Warrior, since their auto-attack causes a single bleed, and the default warrior loadout includes a bleed increase.

In short, conditions only deal damage for full seconds. 7 and 3/4 seconds will still only cause 7 ticks; you need that last 1/4 if you want 8 ticks.

So for bleeds, at least, you want to make sure that you're not wasting traits or runes on half-ticks or quarter-ticks. Either up your bonus duration, or find something else.

For Fire and Poison, it's a little different, because reapplying the condition *extends* the duration. In this case, the duration bonuses are a little better with fractional ticks... as long as you can routinely apply the condition. 5 1/2 sec burn + another 5 1/2 sec burn will give you **11** ticks, which means your bonus duration is not wasted, you just have to put in more effort to get a return on your investment, as it were.

Comment: Good answer, the reapplying of poison and burning durations is something I never thought off.